# Live mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to show an anchor link when a div is hovered.  This is working fine, but when I hover over the link itself, it flashes, when it should just stay.  I tried a regular hover function on the anchor link and that didn't work... This is my js:

```
$('.div_mayKnowUser').live("mouseover", function(){
   $(this).find('.a_ignoreUser').fadeIn();
});
        
$('.div_mayKnowUser').live("mouseout", function(){
   $(this).find('.a_ignoreUser').fadeOut();
});
```

and my HTML:

```
<div class="div_mayKnowUser">
    <a href="" class="a_ignoreUser">a link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: you should use Delegate, chain your jQuery methods and search not by class only, but by Tag name as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"mouseover" => "mouseenter"

"mouseout" => "mouseleave"

worth a read => http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html

**Edit**: regarding live and mouseenter/mouseleave, it seems there's a [known bug](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/strange-behavior-when-using-live-with-mouseenter-mouseleave) that hasn't been fixed, see the examples on the comments.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/2Jy9R/ I think it's a problem with 'live', and event target firing .. if u bind them the problem is solved (like the hover())